# Regular expression to extract dimensions from a string like '2” (7cm) high, 3” (9cm) long and 2” (7cm) wide'

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to extract the physical dimensions of items in a dataset from an unformatted string description. There are quite a few different ways they are expressed in the string. Here are some examples:

```
2” (7cm) high, 3” (9cm) long and 2” (7cm) wide
7” (20cm) high, 5” (15cm) wide and 5” (13cm) deep
4” high, 7” wide and 5” deep
6 inches high, 17 inches wide, and 6 inches deep
```

I am trying to extract them in the most elegant way possible using just a single regular expression for each dimension, ideally, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do it and I don't even know where to start, really. I am using a pandas DataFrame and the [extract()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method, if that makes a difference. Here is what I have so far:

```
r'(?P<height_cm>\d+)cm\) high'
r'?P<width_cm>\d+)cm\) wide'
r'(?P<length_cm>\d+)cm\) [deep|long]'
```

But this obviously only captures the cm numbers. How can I also capture the inches if present? And how can I use either the inch symbol or the word inches so that they both match?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem you want to extract cms values, however cms are not available on all data. I don't think you want to mix cms and inches values. So, what are you trying to extract? Can you give us an example of the expected data to be extracted?

Comment: Do you mean you have several matches per line?

Comment: AFAIK `2”` =~ `5.08 cm`

Comment: Not all lines contain both inches and centimeters so I intend to extract both and then keep only the more frequently mentioned unit (and convert if necessary) later on in the processing pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following examples given (assuming deep and long are the same dimension):

```
(?:(?:((?:(?P<height_inch>\d+)(?:”| inches))(?: \((?P<height_cm>\d+)(?:\s?cm)\))? high)|((?:(?P<deep_inch>\d+)(?:”| inches))(?: \((?P<deep_cm>\d+)(?:\s?cm)\))? (?:deep|long))|((?:(?P<wide_inch>\d+)(?:”| inches))(?: \((?P<wide_cm>\d+)(?:\s?cm)\))? wide)).*?)+
```

Edit: above regex updated to work with `re.fullmatch` and `Series.str.extractall`

This one might be simpler to work with:

```
((?:(?P<inch>\d+)(?:”| inches))(?: \((?P<cm>\d+)(?:\s?cm)\))? (?P<side>high|wide|deep|long))
```

Also use with `Series.str.extractall`

[On regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zxpI7L/3)

Comment: This won't work in Pandas.

Comment: Actually yes, tested it in Pandas, only height values are returned. Made changes to at least work with `re.fullmatch`...

Comment: Ok, with Pandas seems to work with `Series.str.extractall` instead of `Series.str.extract`. Same behavior with `re.match` and `re.fullmatch`.

Comment: This works for me in pandas just fine. Thank you so much! This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Note that these regular expressions will also match strings of the format `x inches (ycm)`. I am assuming that's not a problem.

```
r'(?P<height_inches>\d+)(\”|\sinches)(\((P<height_cm>\d+)\scm\))?\shigh'
r'(?P<width_inches>\d+)(\”|\sinches)(\((P<width_cm>\d+)\scm\))?\swide'
r'(?P<length_inches>\d+)(\”|\sinches)(\((P<length_cm>\d+)\scm\))?\s(deep|long)'
```

Comment: This won't work in Pandas.